# Scala repartition cannot resolve symbol

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, amazon-emr

I am trying to save my dataframe aa parquet file with one partition per day. So trying to use the date column. However, I want to write one file per partition, so using `repartition($"date")`, but keep getting errors:

This error `"cannot resolve symbol repartition"` and `"value $ is not a member of stringContext"` when I use,

```
DF.repartition($"date")
  .write
  .mode("append")
  .partitionBy("date")
  .parquet("s3://file-path/")
```

This error `Type mismatch, expected column, actual string,` when I use:

```
DF.repartition("date")
  .write
  .mode("append")
  .partitionBy("date")
  .parquet("s3://file-path/")
```

However, this works fine without any error.

```
DF.write.mode("append").partitionBy("date").parquet("s3://file-path/")
```

Cant we use date type in repartition? Whats wrong here?

Comment: Did you `import sqlContext.implicits._`?

Comment: I tried, but I couldn’t. It says can not resolve symbol sqlContext

Comment: Ah, with newer versions of Spark that would most likely be `import spark.implicits._` (if you have a `SparkSession` named spark). This will enable you to use the `$` symbol instead of using `col()`.

Comment: Yes. But still it didnt resolve symbol implicits.

Comment: Yes, it is working, i added it after creating spark session. Now it works. Please add it as an answer, i will accept. Thanks.

Comment: No problems, glad I could help solve it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use the `$` symbol inplace of `col()`, you need to first import `spark.implicits`. `spark` here is an instance of a `SparkSession`, hence the import must be done after the creation of a `SparkSession`. A simple example:

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
import spark.implicits._
```

This import will also enable other functionallity such as converting RDDs to Dataframe of Datasets with `toDF()` and `toDS()` respectively.